# Coloring of individual labels in a row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am new to IOS and need some help.I have rows of elements and each row is being filled from an array and the rows are arranged one below the other.The row consists of labels and the labels need to be of different color.This code applies color to entire row insted of individual labels.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, 240)];

 int bx=0;

 for (NSString * str1 in arr1)
 {
    if ([arr1 count]<=2) {
        label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(bx, -1,    scrollView.frame.size.width/[arr1 count], 100)];
        label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
    else
    {
        label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(bx, -1, 106, 100)];
        label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }

    [label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",str1]];
    [scrollView addSubview:label];
    bx +=label.frame.size.width;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to apply differnt colors on UITableViewCell then, 
Take array for storing differnt colors,

then in UITABLEVIEWDATASOURCE method,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// init your cell.

// use below if you have specific number of cells.
[cell.backgroundcolor = [colorarray object at index: indexpath.row]];

or you can do below if it`s suitable to you.
if([indexpath.row % 2 == 0])
{
[cell.backgroundcolor = [uicolor your color]];
}

else
{
[cell.backgroundcolor = [uicolor your different color]];
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply assign a background color to `UILabel` using its backgroundColor`enter code here` property

```
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

put that after you initialize the label